# Java Multithreading: Implementing of important methods in Thread class in Native Libraries?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface

I was reading Thread class and found all major operations of Multithreading are present with native keyword.

```
private native void start0();
private native void setPriority0(int newPriority);
private native void stop0(Object o);
private native void suspend0();
private native void resume0();
private native void interrupt0();
private native void setNativeName(String name);
```

On more research it is found that these are implemented in C Language. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/178f954e1fd1/src/share/native/java/lang/Thread.c

I am trying to search the reason for that Why do Sun/Oracle used Native code for writing such important methods? Is it due to performance or memory level communication only?

Comment: It probably has to do with that multithreading uses system dependent OS calls, which maybe C (for a given platform, Windows, Unix, etc.) has visibility to.

Answer (score 1):

I think as Java is higher level language than C, they have implemented these Thread class method in C. Because for multithreading happened to its optimal level, anyone needs to access the OS and processors. To harness true OS concurrency for faster applications on either uniprocessors or multiprocessors, native languages like C is better than Java in terms of performance. The following links can help you understand the same.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3461/6jck06gqe/

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5137/816-5137.pdf

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032e/index.html

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/index.html